# Google search results is not same as scraping google results, how to get them same?

Tags: python, web-scraping, search, hyperlink

Not able to get the same result while scraping google using bs4 as compared to when I search the same thing in browser.

I have made a web crawler which takes the input of start date, end date,company_name and keyword. These 4 parameters are put into google search. I also have user agent. How can I get the same results through scraping that I get while browsing in google.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from ssl import SSLCertVerificationError
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError
import urllib.parse
import urllib3
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

headers= {  
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",  
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Chrome/113.0.0.0"
  }

start_date=input("Enter start date: ")
end_date=input("Enter end date: ")
company_name=input("Enter company name: ")
keyword=input("Enter keyword: ")
try:
    url_params = {
            'q': f'{company_name} company {keyword} technology ',
            'tbs': f'cdr:1,cd_min:{start_date},cd_max:{end_date}',
            'source': 'lnms',
            'tbm': 'nws'
        }

    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(url_params)

    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')

except (requests.exceptions.SSLError,SSLCertVerificationError,MaxRetryError,requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema,requests.exceptions.MissingSchema,requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects,requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError,TypeError,HTTPError,URLError,ValueError):
    print('Connection failed with this website.')

for links in soup.findAll("a"):
    link=links['href']
    # print(link)
    #Putting the necessary conditions to get a relevant link
    if link[0:4]=='/url' and 'https' in link and 'google.com' not in link and 'proxyDocument' not in link and '.pdf' not in link and 'linkedin.com' not in link and 'cyberghost' not in link and 'cryptojacking' not in link and 'nasdaq.com' not in link and 'thecsr' not in link and 'nokia.com' not in link and 'youtube.com' not in link and 'co.uk' not in link and 'getting-started' not in link and 'scholar.google' not in link and 'quora' not in link and 'isitdown' not in link and 'tapinto' not in link and 'knownews' not in link and 'makeuseof' not in link and 'fordmuscle' not in link and 'marketbeat' not in link and 'statetime' not in link and 'dig-in' not in link:
        #doing the necessary slicing
        stripped_link=link.split('&sa')
        stripped_link.pop()
        #We got our final link 
        final_link=stripped_link[0][7:]
        print(final_link)
print(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the request parameters are different, such as headers, cookies, etc. You can open the developer tools in your browser to see the detail. Additionally, Google customizes search results based on some of your personal account information like your location and so on. Therefore, it is difficult for the results to be exactly the same.